# Install English keyboard layout on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have this Swedish MacBook so it came with a Swedish keyboard. It's almost the same as the English one but they have some additional letters and most of the special symbols are not in the "right" places.

I am really dependent on my keyboard layout in order to do my job efficiently, so this is really important to me, but I can't find a way to install the classic English QWERTY keyboard and remove the Swedish one.

And ideas how to do this?

I have found some apps that let me customize every key, but I suppose there is an easier way…so ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the actual physical constraints where european models have different physical layouts, switching the software to be a US layout is trivial.

Open System Preferences and use the Language & Text preference pane (assuming you are on Mountain Lion - older OS have it named Internationalization) to turn on the US input method.

[image: Language & Text preference pane]

Comment: yep, my problem was that I was searching for "english" instead of U.S. I am new into this mac stuff, so ... some stupid questions occur. Thanks for the help

Comment: Not at all - just knowing it should be there or was there doesn't mean you need to remember where every last option is.